# Eclipse IDE doesn't recognize mysql driver

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

This has been extremely frustrating, especially since I've been all over the forums and have followed all the directions, as far as I can tell.

I am trying to create a connection to a local mysql database.  First I downloaded the mysql driver from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j using the platform independent TAR (I'm on ubuntu).  Then I placed the resultant JAR into a new folder I created for my project call /lib, and then right-clicked and selected "Add to Build Path".  It now shows up as a Referenced Library.

For the code, I am doing the typical things you would do:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String db_url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/project";
    connect = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, "user", "password");
    statement = connect.createStatement();
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from database.table");
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        int id = resultSet.getInt("ID");
        String name = resultSet.getString("Name");
        System.out.println("(ID: " + id + ") (Name: " + name + ")");
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But for whatever reason, I still get "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver cannot be found"

I'm sure it's something completely idiotic on my part, but any pointers as to what I'm missing?

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver cannot be found by com.personal.recipes_1.0.0.qualifier
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at com.personal.recipes.test.TestUtils.execute(TestUtils.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:243)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:224)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:167)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:850)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(HandledContributionItem.java:743)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.access$7(HandledContributionItem.java:727)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$4.handleEvent(HandledContributionItem.java:662)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1392)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3742)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3363)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:162)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Comment: Are you running an application or from a server?  If it's from a server, you may need to add the jar file/s to `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: is it a web application or java application

Comment: what you getting when you write `Driver` in open type( ctrl+shift+T ) ??

Comment: paste the `stacktrace` pls

Comment: I am running a java application. "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" is the first option when I enter ctrl+shift_T and type Driver. I added the stack trace to the main post.  Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Forgot to add that the specific mysql jar I'm importing is "mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jaar".  Is there any possibility that this is an environment issue (i.e., my OS brand/version, the fact that this is in an Eclipse 4 project, something...?)  Seems like a long shot, but I'm completely stumped here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I probably didn't explain my problem well enough before.  The question specifically related to getting my Eclipse RCP application to see the driver.  After talking to a friend he reminded me that I needed to add the mysql jar to the .MF file directly.  Once I knew that I found a ton of posts on various forums answering my question.

I added the following line and I'm able to make the connection to the database without issue:

"Bundle-ClassPath: lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar, ."

The (.) at the end also was very important and stymied me for a few minutes.

Comment: Hello... I am facing the same problem, but with mariaDb. I downloaded the jar and put it in a folder Lib. I added the line "Bundle-ClassPath: /Lib/mariadb-java-client-1.2.3.jar ." at the end of the manifest.mf file. Now it is giving error - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.app.editor.Application cannot be found by com.app.Editor_1.0.0.qualifier.. Do you have any idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

I just made a quick copy / paste of your code into a **fresh** project, installed the driver in lib... works like a charm. So did you do something before the code snippet?
[image: Fresh Project]

Comment: My screen shot looks pretty much exactly like yours.  The only difference is that the code block is in the execute method of a handler class.